# Problemas com a tag <video> no Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, vídeo

Estou com um problema incomum aqui com o Chrome. Com a tag .

Como vocês podem ver na imagem, em comparação com o Firefox o video no Chrome está destorcido.

[image: firefox x chrome]

Upei a parte do código que faz referência a área afetada em questão.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpVbzp